# How to work with result collections from Selenium

Tags: vba, excel, selenium

Or how to work with collections (or arrayss) in VBA.

The issue is most probably myself, but I couldn't find an answer yet.

I am trying to go trough a some pages on a web-site with Selenium-vba to find some data.
As usual if there is more to display, the site shows a 'NEXT' button. The button has `<a href ... >` when the link is activated, else it's just plain text.

To test if there is another page I have found the way to use findElement**s**ByLinkText, and either there is a link or the the collection is empty. So this can be tested by the size of the collection.

This works so far.

But when I try to use the collection (aside from a for each loop) for further action I can't get it to operate.

This is the code:

```
Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
Dim By As New By, Assert As New Assert, Verify As New Verify, Waiter As New Waiter
On Error GoTo ende1

driver.Start "chrome", "http://www.domain.tld/"

driver.setImplicitWait 5000

driver.get "//......."

Set mynext = driver.findElementsByLinkText("Next")
if mynext.Count >0 Then 
 mynext(1).Click             'THIS STATEMENT DOES NOT WORK
End If
```

So please help me to get around my understanding issue (which I am convinced it is)

How can I access an element from the collection.

My workaround so far is to execute

```
 driver.findElementByLinkText("Next").Click
```

but this is unprofessional as it executes the query again.

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the html structure. Are you able to post it? A few possibilities....  if `mynext.Count = 1` then `mynext(0).Click` would work otherwise there are other potential elements with Next. Also, is the link inside a frame?

Answer (score 0):

The Next button is probably loaded asynchonously after the page is completed.
This implies that findElementsByLinkText("Next") returns no elements at the time it's called.
A way to handle this case is to silent the error, adjust the timeout and test the returned element:

```
Dim driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
driver.Get "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=selenium"

Set ele = driver.FindElementByLinkText("Next", Raise:=False, timeout:=1000)
If Not ele Is Nothing Then
  ele.Click
End If

driver.Quit
```

To get the latest version in date working with the above example:
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/latest